# How to ContourPlot $f(x,y) \in 2\pi\mathbb Z$?

Tags: plotting

I want to `CountourPlot` a union of curve
$$ \cos(xy) - x + y = 2 \pi n, \qquad n\in\mathbb Z.$$
on the region $0\leq x,y\leq 10$.

How can I plot the union of curve easily?

I only know an unsystematic and cumbersome approach. One can see (by trial and error) that only for $n=-1,0,1$ the curve lies in $0\leq x,y\leq 10$. Hence, the following gives the correct answer:

```
ContourPlot[{Cos[x y] - x + y == 0, Cos[x y] - x + y == 2 Pi, Cos[x y] - x + y == -2 Pi}, {x, 0, 
  10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

However, my real function is complicated than $\cos(xy)- x + y$, and I want a more systematic approach. How can I do this?

Comment: `ContourPlot[{Cos[x y] - x + y}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
 Contours -> {0, 2 Pi, -2 Pi}, ContourShading -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, PlotPoints -> 50]`

Comment: Do you at least know the approximate range of $n$? Then you can plot all of them: ``ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[Cos[x y] - x + y == 2 n Pi, {n, -10, 10}], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]``.

Comment: Thanks all, and in particular @cvgmt for the simplest and intuitive solution. As many people answer, I need an estimate of effective range of $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram Tech Support CASE: 4909494 (**EDIT: RESOLVED IN VERSION 13.1**)

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Instead of plotting the equation (`Cos[x y] - x + y == 2 n Pi`), plot the expression (`Cos[x y] - x + y`) with the contour values being the `2 n Pi`. While the contours are drawn correctly, they are labeled with the wrong values (i.e., sequenced wrong).

```
With [{n = 1},
 ContourPlot[
  Cos[x y] - x + y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},
  Contours -> Range[-2 n Pi, 2 n Pi, 2 Pi],
  ContourLabels -> All,
  ContourShading -> None,
  MaxRecursion -> 3]]
```

[image]

Compare the contour labels with

```
With [{n = 1},
 ContourPlot[
  Cos[x y] - x + y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},
  Contours -> 3,
  ContourShading -> None,
  ContourLabels -> All,
  MaxRecursion -> 3]]
```

[image]

To show the correct labels,

```
With [{n = 1},
 Show[
  ContourPlot[
     Cos[x y] - x + y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},
     Contours -> {#},
     ContourLabels -> All,
     ContourShading -> None,
     MaxRecursion -> 3] & /@
   Range[-2 n Pi, 2 n Pi, 2 Pi]]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For multiple functions

```
With[{n = 1},
 Show[
  Outer[
   ContourPlot[#1,
     {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8},
     Contours -> {#2},
     ContourLabels -> All,
     ContourShading -> None,
     PlotPoints -> 50,
     MaxRecursion -> 3,
     ImageSize -> 400] &,
   {Cos[x y] - x + y, x + y},
   Range[-2 n Pi, 2 n Pi, 2 Pi]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. Is there any reason for your first and second examples giving the wrong labels?

Comment: The first plot shows that there is a bug with the labeling (hence the referenced bug report to Wolfram Tech Support). The second plot is correct, however, the default contour levels are not the contours that you want. The third plot shows how to get what you want.

Comment: How should I modify the last code if I want multiple plots? Suppose that I want to plot the unions of $f(x,y) \in 2\pi \mathbb Z$ and $g(x,y)\in 2\pi\mathbb Z$. Letting $g(x,y) = x+y$ for example, the following trial did not work:

`With [{n = 5},
 Show[
  ContourPlot[
     {Cos[x y] - x + y,x+y}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},
     Contours -> {#},
     ContourLabels -> All,
     ContourShading -> None,
     MaxRecursion -> 3] & /@
   Range[-2 n Pi, 2 n Pi, 2 Pi]]]`

Comment: See edit. To show more than one contour for the second function, I changed the plot range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

By using [`Mod`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod.html) with an offset, we can plot these contours without pre-computing the range of $n$:

```
ContourPlot[Mod[Cos[x y] - x + y, 2π, -π] == 0, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]